# lottery program with rand number

Tags: c++, numbers

I am trying to write programs that generates three digit number for the lottery and the user enters three digits.

- If the user input matches the lottery in exact order , the award is $10,000.
- If the user input matches the lottery ,the award is $3,000.
- If one digit in the user input matches a digit in the lottery , the award is $1,000

But I don't get any correct result.

```
h1=rand() % 10;

int h2=rand() % 10;
int h3=rand() % 10;

cout<<"Enter three digite number\n";
cin>>n1>>n2>>n3;

if(n1==h1&&n2==h2&&n3==h3)
    cout<<"you win 10.000 award\n";
else
    if(n1==h1||n1==h2||n1==h3&&n2==h1||n2==h2||n2==h3&&n3==h1||n3==h2||n3==h3)
        cout<<"you win 3,000\n";
    else
        if(n1==h1||n1==h2||n1==h3||n2==h1||n2==h2||n2==h3||n3==h1||n3==h2||n3==h3)
            cout<<"you win 1,000\n";
        else
            cout<<"you don't win anything sorry\n";
```

Comment: Is it acceptable that you can draw the same number twice (or three times)? Is it acceptable that draws are not evenly distributed?

Answer (score 1):

Your test conditions in the second and third if blocks are incorrect.

```
if(n1==h1||n1==h2||n1==h3&&n2==h1||n2==h2||n2==h3&&n3==h1||n3==h2||n3==h3)
```

In this test condition, there are many problems.

- First, this is prone to being short-circuited. If n1 matches h1 or h2 the rest of the condition does not get tested. The same applies to every comparison after that keeping in mind the && in which both conditions on its sides will need to be true for short-circuiting.
- Assuming we put brackets that prevent this, then your condition will be true for all three matching in any order.

Seeing these two problems, it is best to rework the logic as this makes the action of the third block redundant. Your third block will run for a certain combination of inputs and not what you expect it to do

---

I think a better way to code your program logic would be to compare each character individually and maintain a counter for the number of matches found.

```
int c=0, win;
if(n1==h1||n1==h2||n1==h3) c++;
if(n2==h1||n2==h2||n2==h3) c++;
if(n3==h1||n3==h2||n3==h3) c++;

if(c==3)
{
    //Check order of digits
    if(n1==h1&&n2==h2&&n3==h3) win = 10000;
    else win=3000 //All digits same but not in order
}
else if(c==2)
    win=3000
else if(c==1)
    win=1000
else
    win=0

if(win) cout<<"You win "<<win<<"\n";
else cout<<"you dont win anything\n";
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to add an explanation for why the solution presented by the OP did not work.

Comment: @Suno87 If it worked out, then select this as the correct answer.